# How do alternate row colors in an SSRS 2008 report?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm trying to alternate row colors in one of my reports.  So following some advice from the web, I've tried putting something like this for the background color of the rows in question:

```
=IIF(RowNumber('manager') Mod 2, "LightBlue","White")
```

Where manager is the name of my row group.

But what this does is make the color alternate every time a value is present.  And some of the rows that aren't even supposed to be colored get colored.  I really don't get it, but perhaps the fact that there's a column group is messing things up somehow?

I've also tried numbering each row in my query and going off that but I still get the same weirdness.

And I even tried returning the color in my query and it gets even stranger because then every single row is colored Light blue, and again even the ones that aren't supposed to get colored. Just Visual Studio being buggy as always I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

RowNumber('manager') resets to 1 when you get a break in the manager group. So rows under that manager may toggle.

=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2=0, "LightBlue","White") seems to work OK with Nothing in the group.

As you said, you can also number each row in the result set (identity column?). Then you want to check the value of your numbered column rather than use the RowNumber function.

=IIF(Fields!id.Value Mod 2 = 0, "LightBlue","White")